# Error in jupyter notebook, can not specify kernel

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pip, jupyter, conda

I was running my jupyter notebook, however I got this error sign for few hours.

```
Starting Kernel 
Unhandled error
```

I have tried to run to reinstall the jupyter (based on [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/looking-for-help-with-a-kernel-error/4528/3)), however I cant remove them.

here is the list of my kernal for jupyter

```
$jupyter kernelspec list

bash: /mnt/biostat/environments/parkj/fastai_env/bin/jupyter: /mnt/biostat/environments/parkj/fastai_env/bin/python3.11: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

and info about my python and jupyter.

```
 which python
/mnt/biostat/environments/parkj/fastai_env/bin/python
 which jupyter
/mnt/biostat/environments/parkj/fastai_env/bin/jupyter
```

Comment: needed to delete the /.local file and reinstall the conda env and pip libries